# Error while reading txt file in R

Tags: r, read.table

I'm wondering if I can get help with the following error I encounter while reading a txt file using read.table in R.

My txt file is formatted like this :

```
Subject ID  Span    Accuracy    Accuracy (SD)   Avg RT  Avg RT (SD) Median RT   Number of Trials    Date/Time   
1   2   1   0   3206    1702.713    3206    2   08/23/2016 12:54:13
1   3   1   0   2485.5  12.021  2485.5  2   08/23/2016 12:54:13
1   4   1   0   3513    0   3513    1   08/23/2016 12:54:13
```

I run the code

```
test <- read.table('test.txt', sep = "\t")
```

And I will get the error

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 2 did not have 10 elements
```

However, if I include only the header in the txt and remove the following data rows, I can run the same code and get:

```
> test
          V1   V2       V3            V4     V5          V6        V7               V8        V9
1 Subject ID Span Accuracy Accuracy (SD) Avg RT Avg RT (SD) Median RT Number of Trials Date/Time
```

If I remove the header from the txt and include only the data rows in the txt, I can also run the same code and get:

```
> test
  V1 V2 V3 V4     V5       V6     V7 V8                  V9
1  1  2  1  0 3206.0 1702.713 3206.0  2 08/23/2016 12:54:13
2  1  3  1  0 2485.5   12.021 2485.5  2 08/23/2016 12:54:13
3  1  4  1  0 3513.0    0.000 3513.0  1 08/23/2016 12:54:13
```

It seems both the header and data contain 9 elements, but I get the error saying "line 2 did not have 10 elements" if I include both header and data rows in the same txt file. I tried using header = FALSE but it gives the same error.

I would appreciate if some one can help me with this problem. I have a large number of txt files formatted the same way so it is unrealistic for me to open each txt and manually remove the header line.

Thanks！

Comment: This is probably because there is a space character between the date and time values of your column `Date/Time`.

Comment: Perhaps viewing whitespace in your favorite editor might shed some light on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there are ten columns stated in the header section. If you import only the header, the column **Subject** is used as label for the row names.

So either you have to include row names for the actual data (which will be the 10th column) or you have to exclude **Subject** from your input file.

For verification purposes, I just deleted the **Subject** term from the header section and it was successfully read as data frame with 3 observations and 9 variables.

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L), Span = 2:4, Accuracy = c(1L, 1L, 1L), Accuracy..SD. = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Avg.RT = c(3206, 2485.5, 3513), Avg.RT..SD. = c(1702.713, 12.021, 0), Median.RT = c(3206, 2485.5, 3513), Number.of.Trials = c(2L, 2L, 1L), Date.Time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "08/23/2016 12:54:13", class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "Span", "Accuracy", "Accuracy..SD.", "Avg.RT", "Avg.RT..SD.", "Median.RT", "Number.of.Trials", "Date.Time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```